# How to allow profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera for all windows

Tags: selenium, testing, notifications, load-testing

I am doing load testing for particular URL in Selenium where in between of flow it ask for Camera permission. 
Now i have added this code->

```
ChromeOptions options=new ChromeOptions();
        Map<String, Object> prefs=new HashMap<String,Object>();
        prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera", 1);
        //1-Allow, 2-Block, 0-default
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs",prefs);
```

Now when i run this for load testing, let say same 10 flow running simultaneously at same time, so only visible browser passes the allow for camera, rest 9 browserwhich are running at backgroud does not cater to this.
How can i give input so all 10 browser will cater to allow notifications?

Comment: did you got a solution for this?

Comment: No did not got any solutions